# Angular global error handler with service dependency

Tags: angularjs, configuration, error-handling

Trying to create a global error handler that should present an error modal on error by configuring the $httpProvider adding a interceptor. The modal produces a dependency on a service. Which I can't inject into a config block. 
I have tried lazy loading the service using $injector, but doesn't work. 
How would you solve it?

edit just found $exceptionHandler, trying it. No luck cirk dep :$modal <- errorModalService <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope

Comment: Please show as much relevant code as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true that AngularJS DI subsystem can be tricky with circular dependencies. Not sure what you've tried and what didn't work but you can always get a required dependency from the `$injector`. Doing so from a `$http` interceptor is pretty easy:

```
  .factory('errInterceptor', function ($q, $injector) {
    return {
      responseError: function(response) {
          $injector.get('$modal').open({
            template: '<h4>$http error!</h4>',
          });
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/n172IrR9259qi4qG0H3I?p=preview

Comment: looks promising, trying it now!